# JBOSS EAP SERVER NOT RESPONDING

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have an application deployed on JBOSS EAP 7.2 in standalone mode the application works fine and it's behind an apache reverse proxy, after some time accessing the application using the browser gives a 502 proxy error at the time the jboss server isn't down and if you perform a curl for the same page using localhost the curl command timesout, indicating the error is not related to the proxy.

the log is filled with java exceptions and errors but not the same error each time and when the server stops responding to curl the jboss server stops logging.

It should be noted that the application is accessed by a large number of users.

I'm looking for assumptions about the root cause, if you guys have any ideas it would be very great.

What could cause this?

Comment: What kind of exceptions are you seeing?

Comment: - javax.el.ELException, a lot of java.lang.NullPointerException, javax.faces.FacesException, java.io.IOException: Broken pipe.  can any of these cause the server to be unresponsive? I've also looked at gc logs and it seems there are no probs from the side of memory.

Comment: They could be for sure. You'd need to look at the full stack trace and examine where it might be coming from.

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to figure out if it's an application error so i can pass it to the DEV team, as I don't have any experience with java. Thank you

Comment: The stack traces would need to be examined to determine that.